# Filtering the view without actually filtering the underlying data, while using table calculations in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have 2 columns in my tableau, `user_id` and `createdAt`. `user_id` as the id of the users, and `createdAt` as the date transaction happen.

This is my tableau

[image]

I take this user_id = 60 as the example, so I have 2 filters, for the conditions users (PUL : true)

and date_range : true so the data will appear on date range

on my tableau, i made calculated field called datediff with this query

```
DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))
```

so this calculated field has a function to count the different day between transaction for each users in date range (on this case, i choose range between '2020-01-01' until '2020-01-31')

as you can see,on date range for user_id 60 has 2 transactions, its january 10 and january 31, and for that reason, its 21 day different between those date. but if i put out the date_range filter you can see all the date of transaction for user_id = 60, you can see on this

[image]

as we know, before the date range, user_id = 60 has did the transaction on 24th december 2019, which means 17 days behind.

my question is, how to made the time difference between the transaction on first date in date_range, and compare it to last transaction before date range, so when i put the date_range filter, on january 10th 2020 (for user_id = 60) its also appear the 17 days time difference on column january 10th 2020 (because its compare with last date transaction before the date range which means on 24th december 2019).

which part i should edit or add?

Comment: Fachry it will be better if you upload some data in csv, every time so that the problem can be handled well.

Comment: sorry, let me upload the data

Comment: can i sent in to your email? because stackoverflow cant upload the data

Comment: i mean upload csv

Comment: see the solution.  The basic idea is to make filter on a table calculated field if working with table calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used sample data previously taken by me to solve your another problem.

sample data used

[image]

Create a calculated field `date for filter` as

```
lookup(min(([Trans Date])),0)
```

Right-click this measure and click `convert to continuous`

use this field as filter instead, you will get what you want.

Two screenshots

[image]

and filtered view

[image]

**EDIT: Since you have used parameters, use this calculation in `date range` field instead**

```
lookup(min(([Trans Date])),0) >= [Start date] and 
lookup(min(([Trans Date])),0) <= [End date]
```

see this screenshot

[image]

Needless to say `trans date` is your `created at` field.

Comment: this is my date_range: true [Created At] >= [START_DATE] AND [Created At] <= [END_DATE]

Comment: its still empty, and not counting time different between first date on date range and last date before date range